# iTunes can't set shuffle mode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scripting-bridge

I'm using the scripting bride to have my mac app connect into iTunes. I try to set the shuffle property, but it won't change.

```
iTunesApplication *itunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.itunes"];
itunes.currentPlaylist.shuffle = YES;
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%hhd", itunes.currentPlaylist.shuffle]);
```

The NSLog will always print 0, even if I change the shuffle mode manually in iTunes. I have the same issue with setting the repeat mode

```
itunes.currentPlaylist.songRepeat = iTunesERptAll; // Has no effect
```

On the other hand, I can change the volume without a problem

```
itunes.soundVolume += 20;
```

What's going on here? Could it be that I have to go through the currentPlaylist property?

**EDIT:** I've updated my iTunes.h file with

```
sdef /Applications/iTunes.app | sdp -fh --basename iTunes
```

and still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a bit, I learned I'm not the only person with this issue. It's a bug in iTunes. I've also filed a bug report and would encourage you to do the same!

Comment: Just a thought... while you can't turn on/off iTunes/Music shuffle, you can play a random track: [[self.MusicApp.currentPlaylist.tracks objectAtIndex:arc4random() % self.MusicApp.currentPlaylist.tracks.count] playOnce:YES];